# system.err style console print in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging, console.log

I recently discovered that doing something like:

```
console.dir(x)
```

is NOT instantaneous, but is rather buffered, and beyond that, it prints the state of the variable x when the printing is actually done, as opposed to when the console.dir(x) was called.  This means that if x changes between when I called the console.dir(x) and when the console.dir(x) actually prints, it is impossible to view the state of x at a particular point in time and be guaranteed to view the state of x at that point in time.

Is there a way to stop everything and print the state of x, and then continue, similar to how System.err works in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Angular you could try `console.dir(angular.copy(x));`. This will print a copy of the object when it's logged so that it doesn't later display any mutations that occurred. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2qdLvwz/).

Alternatively you could do `console.log(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2));`

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction, because it solves the problem of x changing after the call is made but before the print statement executes.  Is there no such thing as the philosophical equivalent of system.err / stderr in javascript?

Comment: Well system.err will print the object exactly as it is when the logging function is called (iiuc). Either of the two of the two snippets above will accomplish that, so in that sense they're equivalent. The problem with `console.dir()` is that it's logging the actual object, which is mutable in JS, to an interactive console. So the current state of that object is reflected in the console. If the object changes, you see that change.

Comment: Also the problem isn't that 'x is changing after the call is made but before the print statement executes', necessarily. The problem is that the object's contents are changing before you look at the the thing in the console. You could also try putting a breakpoint there or using a `debugger;` call to examine the object.